# What does Windows Firewall do if I don't add a specific firewall rule?

Tags: windows, security, firewall, windows-firewall, internet-security

Suppose I have a program which needs to connect to the Internet in order to work. Let's also say that I only want this program to communicate on private networks, so I add a firewall rule allowing it to communicate on private connections.

If I don't want it to work on public connections, should I explicitly add a new blocking firewall rule or would Windows Firewall automatically block the traffic on public networks for this program (i.e. following a *whitelist approach*, where everything is blocked by default)?

Comment: Depends on the specific program.  Most programs don't need a firewall rule to work.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, I was referring to programs which need a firewall rule to work

Comment: Are you talking about outbound connections, where the program connects to a server on the internet, or inbound connections, where a machine on the internet connects to the program?

Comment: @HarryJohnston both :)

Comment: By default, outbound connections are a blacklist, and inbound connections are a whitelist.  But that's configurable.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks! Where can I configure the general behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, outbound connections are a blacklist, and inbound connections are a whitelist.

However, you can configure this behaviour from the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security control panel (go to Windows Firewall and click on Advanced Settings).

To do this, right-click on the topmost node in the left-hand pane ("Windows Firewall with Advanced Security") and select Properties.